# How does sqlite work with javascript in Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon

How can I use sqlite? What is the command when I want to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

? (I mean like PHP I need to use `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");`)

What is the command when I get a table with records and I want to dispart it? (in PHP: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array()`)

I used `SELECT * FROM table` in the table var and I dispart it. (The table has these columns: `id, name, pass`) How can I get the column values?

This is the connection in the Javascript to the database:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

let file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["my_db_file_name.sqlite"]);
let mDBConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
```

How can I create table (if it doesn't exist), how can I `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ect.

How can I do this with javascript and sqlite:
example (its wrote in php, mysql):

```
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); // pass if need
mysql_select_db("my_database");

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `my_database`.`table` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,`nev` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,`pass` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,INDEX ( `nev` )) ENGINE = InnoDB HARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name,pass) VALUES ('Peter','sdf')");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['name'].' '.$row['pass']; // it write all record, like 'name pass' ('Peter sdf')
}

$row2=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1"));
echo $row2['name'].' '.$row2['pass']; // it write only 'Peter sdf'

mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=1");

mysql_query("DROP TABLE 'table'");

mysql_close();
```

How can I do this in javascript with sqlite?

Comment: oh and I want to commpatible whit firefox 3.0 and better, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Mozilla Storage API for working with SQLite databases. See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Storage.

Comment: @gold: And what exactly did you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

There is an 3rd party lib to use sqlite with firefox addon API:
https://github.com/julianceballos/sqlite-jetpack

In fact the library is just a simple wrapper (look at the source code).